# C#, RestSharp, Type or Namespace name "HttpBasicAuthenticator" could not be found

Tags: api, rest, visual-studio-2015, restsharp

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using RestSharp;

    namespace ConsoleProgram
    {
        public class TryingOutRest {
            public resttest Execute<resttest>(RestRequest request) where resttest : new() {
            var client = new RestClient();
                client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://www.ocrwebservice.com");
                client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("apid", "apikey");
// the key and and id are put in as a string, but i removed them for the purposes of this.
            var re_quest = new RestRequest();
            re_quest.Resource = "/restservices/processDocument";
            var response = client.Execute<resttest>(request);
            }
    }
    }
```

So, hi, trying to get to grips with Rest api, Currently doing a project involving it and OCR, as you can probably tell. Tried this, i thought it would work fine, but I seem to have messed up dearly or some naming has changed and i cant find anything relevant in the autofill menu.
Anyone got any idea what's happening?
P.s. if questions about install, i used NuGet for that, so i assume there'd be no problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
```

This seems to be the namespace for `HttpBasicAuthenticator` now. ([Github](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Authenticators/HttpBasicAuthenticator.cs))

Comment: @N.Olsen glad to help. Don't forget to mark this as the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). :-)

Answer (score 0):

Open Nugetpackage manager and install RestSharp
Then you can use
using RestSharp.Authenticators